# Review a minor suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I just reviewed a [suggested edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/84453):

[image]

My first reaction was: what invisible edit was made to the text ( e.g. insert `<BR>`) to get this minimal edit in the queue. Then I noticed I had seen that gravatar before, that the editor has 17K6 reputation and that the proposed change was made in 2013 (when the editor had less then 2K rep.)

I briefly suspected that we now have review audits on U&L, but accepting the proposed change did not give any feedback to that effect.

- There were no more edits than the change to the title. Nowadays you need to make larger changes for the system to accept them (at least on sites where I recently started with a low rep). When was the restriction of making larger minimal changes introduced?
- Was this delay a result of a bug in the software? Or from some edge case in the database? If so what triggered this to show up in the review queue?
- Was it an accident that this showed up, or are there more of these cases and are they being fed into the system at a low rate?

If this behaviour cannot be explained and/or is not intentional, I would consider it a bug.

For those wondering about it: the editor did get his +2 rep for an accepted edit. I hope it was worth the wait.

Comment: I had a similar edit review over on AU: http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/399648 - the edit was on a post that was deleted nearly a year ago. O.o

Answer (score 3):

[A bug in suggested edits was tracked down where](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289747/suggested-edit-from-2012-in-review-queue) around 100 older suggested edits had been missed¹.

---

¹ <sub>Do I get a special badge now, having reviewed one of these unique suggested edits?</sub>